# iOS - how to update a database table row

Tags: ios, core-data

I am an iOS development newbie. I am storing the following info in my database -

User: A
Gender: M
School: XYZ

now, I just want to update that row to look like

User: A
Gender: M
School: ABC

So basically I want to change only 1 value. How would I do it using iOS database methods? Should I delete the row and insert it back? Or is there a way to update?

Answer (score 0):

Change the property and save the context.

```
myUser.school = @"ABC";
NSError *error = nil;
[myUser.managedObjectContext save:&error];
// Check if error is not nil.
```

This will do whatever it needs to do to update the persistence layer, be it SQL, flat files or in memory.

Comment: won't this just insert another row in the table?